# Is a snubber for transformer primary winding necessary?

Tags: transformer, snubber

When there is a inductor in the circuit and is being switched on and off it is necessary to put diode across that inductor to prevent high voltage overshoots.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmk2xM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In case of AC voltage this diode protection is not possible and instead of that is used a snubber of some sort. Across the switch or switched load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpuRx2.png)</sup>

But what about primary side of transformers? It is a inductive load, right? Is a snubber required or recommended? All the circuits I found have no snubber. They all seem to be basically like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMoCgt.png)</sup>

But there has to be some switch at the primary side. Should there be some RC snubber?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a conventional transformer, the primary and secondary are strongly coupled.

If the switch opens when there is a large flux in the core, when the flux collapses it induces a voltage in both primary and secondary. The secondary will typically be loaded with a rectifier and large capacitor, which will absorb the energy and clamp the voltage (of both windings) to safe levels.

There is an element of transformer inductance that is not loaded by the secondary, and that's the leakage inductance. This tends to be very small in power transformers, and stores little energy, which is easily handled by an adequate rating for the mains switch.

Comment: There is also a risk that extra components at the mains voltage can cause trouble after many years. The capacitor could blow. Dust could collect around the components and start to leak current. Those two extra components require a lot for the board design to prevent all of that.

Comment: The uncoupled inductance can be measured by short-circuiting the secondary and then measuring primary inductance.  An "adequate rating for the mains switch" will not avoid a spark from that inductance, and while that may not damage the switch, it can cause a real bang if we are talking about switching off an audio amplifier.  Guess what problem made me find this question...

Comment: @Jot an X2-safety class RC snubber capacitor is a single component from the outside with a self-healing capacitor.  It costs money and requires space (not necessarily on a board).  But it is certified in order not to be a safety risk and does not really involve "a lot for the board design".  It will eat up a few mW in on-state when placed across the transformer.

Answer (score 2):

Mains transformer typically much larger than high frequency one and has quite big stray capacitance, which works like a snubber. Also, if this capacitance isn's enough to prevent arcing in a switch, this arc forms loop for inductive current. Typical mechanical switch can handle such arc without problems.