# Reduce switching noise on autotransformer

Tags: noise, switching, snubber, autotransformer

I am trying to achieve the same thing they are talking about in [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/406425/262489), which is controling an autotransformer via software. I accidently even got the exact same autotransformer, but instead of a relay/SSR board from ebay/aliexpress I wanted to be fancy and built my own board, driving the relays by shift register via mosfet drivers.

This all works well until I connect a load. Switching even an incandescent light will generate enough noise to load the shift register with garbage and wreak havoc on the outputs.

I've read [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/344963/262489) and I think snubbers might be the way to go, but I'm not quite sure where to put them and how to calculate the values for R and C.

Comment: Good circuit layout and a sensible wiring regime is usually 90% of the battle.

Comment: I went over my layout again and immediately tripped over a "230V mains antenna" running directly parallel to the shift register data traces. They do have some ground plane around them, but it's nowhere near enough (no stitching either), and the braindead routing of the power trace had it neatly coupled to ground and data lines. After cutting and re-routing the trace, switching resistive loads works fine now, and I haven't seen any noise on the data line (haven't checked the clocks yet, but I assume they look better now, too). With an inductive load, however, some issues remain.